# forward request from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsp-tags

I have a jsp page "one.jsp" which has a button.
On clicking the button I want to call "two.jsp" with the same request object. I tried several options:-
1)on button click, send the request to servlet which forwards the request to "two.jsp" with the help of request dispatcher but was unable to use the request object parameter that "one.jsp" used.
2)made active link and used response.sendredirect() but that creates a new request.
I searched on internet and got `<jsp:forward page="two.jsp">` but I dont know how to do jsp forward on button click.

Comment: If you're seeing the button in your browser, then that means that you got the response from the first request (to one.jsp), and thus that the request used to serve this page has ended for a long time. You should read how HTTP works: a request, a response, that's all. As soon as a request has been handled, it's terminated. When you click on your button, you send another, different request.

Comment: @JBNizet Is there anyway so that i can use the request parameters that i used to render "one.jsp" in "two.jsp"?

Comment: Send them again when clicking your button. If the button is a link, use a query string in the URL: `two.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2`. If it's a form, use hidden fields: `<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

one.jsp

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="servletToJsp">
<input type="submit"></button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

two.jsp

```
 <html>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1> I have been invoked by 
<% 
out.print(request.getAttribute("servletName").toString());
%>
Servlet
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WebPrj</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>servletToJsp</display-name>
    <servlet-name>servletToJsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servletToJsp</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletToJsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletToJsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servletToJsp.java inside com package

```
package com;

 import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class servletToJsp extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    request.setAttribute("servletName", "servletToJsp");

    try {
      getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
        "/two.jsp").forward(request,response);

    } catch (ServletException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this would create new request, I want to use the request parameters of one.jsp

Comment: than set those values in hidden parameter in one.jsp.